# Brand new brake pads still squealing

Tags: toyota, brakes, sienna

Just replaced the front pads on my 2009 Toyota Sienna and the classic brake squeal noise is still happening, and definitely from the front and not the rear. Any ideas on what might be causing this?  Do I need the brake grease in some spot I might have missed?

Thanks

Comment: what kind if pad material did you use? did you put in new clips? grease the caliper bolts?

Answer (score 2):

If you greased the spring and sides as normal, the only other "trick" that I have found that may work is to gently bevel the pad leading edge so it is not square.

Answer (score 0):

Squeal is not always just between the pad and the rotor. The squeal is caused by tiny rapid vibrations throughout the assembly.

This [Popular Mechanics article](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/a3092/4317748/) describes it well;

> Under the right conditions, the disc, the pads and the caliper they're
>   mounted in can start to vibrate—in exactly the same way a violin's
>   string vibrates when stroked by the horsehairs on the bow.

Ways to avoid this are,

1. Use coated shims or the anti-squeal compound between the caliper and
   the pads.
2. Lube the caliper slides to ensure the caliper is free to float (corrosion can buildup causing them to bind).
3. Have the rotors machined or replaced to ensure they are true.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to sand down the pad a little bit, so that you have a new surface to mate with the rotor.  While you are at it, I would bevel the edges, which another answer suggests.